# R: Applying a function to every element of a dataframe

Tags: r, function

For example, lets use the following dataframe composed of strings:

```
df <- data.frame(X = LETTERS[1:3], Y = LETTERS[4:6], row.names = c("r1", "r2", "r3"), stringsAsFactors = F)

> df
   X Y
r1 A D
r2 B E
r3 C F
```

Now, I'd like to apply this function to each element of the dataframe:

```
my_f <- function(x) paste0(x, x)
```

Which should produce this result:

```
>df
    X  Y
r1 AA DD
r2 BB EE
r3 CC FF
```

I've been using nested for loops:

```
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]) {
    for (j in 1:dim(df)[2]) {
        df[i, j] = my_f(df[i, j])
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is a shorter/faster way to achieve the same result? Note that the ouput must be a dataframe with the same rows' and colums' names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `strrep` by looping over the columns of dataset with `lapply`.  The `[]` will restore the same 'data.frame' structure.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, strrep,2)
df
#   X  Y
#r1 AA DD
#r2 BB EE
#r3 CC FF
```

Comment: @agenis Yes, I think `strrep` should be more fast

Comment: Mind explaining the difference between `df`and `df[]`? If I use `df[]<-apply(df,2,my_f)` it works but without `[]` it loses the rownames.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution without any apply-function:

```
df[] <- my_f(as.matrix(df))
```

Answer (score 2):

You already have the answer.

You can `apply` your function `my_f` for every element rowwise (`margin = 1`)

```
data.frame(t(apply(df, 1,my_f)))

#    X1 X2
#r1 AA DD
#r2 BB EE
#r3 CC FF
```

And as @m0h3n suggested, you can avoid the `t`ranspose step by applying the function column-wise (`margin=2`)

```
data.frame(apply(df, 2,my_f))
```

Comment: If you go for `margin=2`, you won't need to transpose.

Comment: Just a sidenote, only this solution does not need a `df[] <-` assignment to produce a `data.frame`, i.e. you can do `new_df <- apply(df, 2, my_f)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using for loops

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$X[i] <- paste0(df$X[i],df$X[i],collapse = "")
  df$Y[i] <- paste0(df$Y[i],df$Y[i],collapse = "")
}

print(df)

  X  Y
r1 AA DD
r2 BB EE
r3 CC FF
```